# Highcharts scatter plot with time only

Tags: javascript, highcharts, scatter-plot

I'm thinking about easiest way of doing scatter plot like here http://www.highcharts.com/demo/scatter which will have on xAxis only 24 hours, but each dot/triangle/sign will state about about data added that corresponding hour but the day/year will be different.
"datetime" type of plot doesn't resolve problem. Is there another way than "hack" the data and change all years, months and days to be the same date? (I'll still have to know about original date, as period that I want to show dots from might be changed by some button).

To be more specific:

Lets say I want to show something like that: jsfiddle.net/Fishman/N6YZX (sugar level in blood at specific hour during the day in some period of time) - I had to change "data" dates to all be the same yyy-mm-dd to show it in scatter (user will be able to change the period that provides data). But the proper data will be like that: jsfiddle.net/Fishman/gPpSW/1 (look at data values). Is there any way to set the scatter plot to ignore date and take into account only time (hour, min, sec)?

Comment: Lets say I want to show something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/Fishman/N6YZX/ 
(sugar level in blood at specific hour during the day in some period of time) - I had to change "data" dates to all be the same yyy-mm-dd to show it in scatter (user will be able to change the period that provides data).

But the proper data will be like that: http://jsfiddle.net/Fishman/gPpSW/1/ (look at data values). Is there any way to set the scatter plot to ignore date and take into account only time (hour, min, sec)?

Comment: add this comment to your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plot them using separate x axis. (set xAxis: 0 in series 0, xAsix:1 in series 1 etc.) You can hide the extra axis. See [show two different series with different start intervals with the same xAxis highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200270/show-two-different-series-with-different-start-intervals-with-the-same-xaxis-hig) for some info on hiding the extra axis titles.

The alternative is to modify the x values to be all the same date. If you still want to display the date in the tooltip, you can add an extra date field to the point and use a custom tooltip to display it.

```
{x:Date.UTC(2013, 03, 05, 9), y:100, origdate:Date.UTC(2013, 03, 03, 9), 100},
{x:Date.UTC(2013, 03, 05, 9), y:100, origdate:Date.UTC(2013, 03, 04, 9), 100},
{x:Date.UTC(2013, 03, 05, 9), y:100, origdate:Date.UTC(2013, 03, 05, 9), 100},
```

Comment: That is good point, but it means, that I'll have to add as many axes as are days (with data) in tracking period. Let say I want to have half-year view (or even year), it means, I have to put there over 180 xAxes... Sounds kind'a dirty. Oh, and there is need to ensure, that proper data series have proper xAxis assigned :/ (updated http://jsfiddle.net/Fishman/5aNEf/1/ for overview)

Comment: So this is the solution I know, I can have. I'd go back to my main question:  Is there another way than "hack" the data and change all years, months and days to be the same date?

Comment: I can't see any other options here I'm afraid.